# renew facebook access token in android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

What is the best way to renew facebook SDK's access token in an Android app?
So far what I've been doing in each splash screen, is to invoke the facebook SDK and to get the access token (if changed or stayed the same, I dont care) and I pass it on to my server.

Is there a less dirty way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a way yet? I'm confused about it too.

Answer (score 0):

when You first time login then store access token in Sharedprefrence which store value still apk is uninstalled so next time u can get value from shared prefrence

// Create object of SharedPreferences.
     SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
    //now get Editor
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
    //put your value
     editor.putString("accestoken", strName);
   //commits your edits
     editor.commit();

**get value**
      SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
     String access_token=sharedPref.getString("accestoken",null);

`if(accesstoken!=null || !accesstoken.equal())
 {
 }`

Comment: But what if had been expired after 60 days? I prefer calling facebook every app launch to validate that...